# Best way to approach re/moving single items from nested array in object, React / Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

the data looks like

```js
const curObject = {
  "2020-06-15": [
    { id: "1", name: "something 1" },
    { id: "6", name: "something 6" },
  ],
  "2020-06-14": [
    { id: "1", name: "something 1" },
    { id: "15", name: "something 15" },
  ],
};
```

Im using hooks /

```
const [curObject, setCurObject] = useState();
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState();
```

I am trying to create two specific pieces of functionality, remove and move.
I have access to the date and id and am decently new to JS.

I started by trying something like

```js
let currentDateArray = [];
let nonCurrentDateArray = [];

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(curObject)) {
  if (key == date) {
    currentDateArray.push({ title: key, data: value });
  }
  if (key !== date) {
    nonCurrentDateArray.push({ title: key, data: value });
  }
}
```

but then I got a little tripped up on {value} being an array and how to filter/ignore this item.

Seems like I'm creating more code than I need... and I'm not even to the point where i have to merge the two.  Anyone have a better way of doing something like this?

tldr:
each element's name is a "YYYY-MM-DD" date, this element is an array, each array only contains id, name.

trying to 'delete' an item in the array in one case, or 'move' the item to a different "YYYY-MM-DD".

edit:
looking for a function approach

```
const modifyCurrentObjectState =(selectedDate,selectedId, destinationDate ,action)=>{
  let tempObject = curObject
  // get tempObject[selectedDate].id == {selectedId}
  // remove from temp object
  // if (action == 'MOVE') { !tempObject[destinationDate] ? tempObject[destinationDate] = [{id: selectedId}] : tempObject[destinationDate].push({id:selectedId})
  // merge?
  handleStateStorageChange('AGENDA',tempObject)
}
```

Comment: so you want to filter curObject and separate data based on some logic and you need two different result array?

Comment: i have a temp = current state, modify temp, save back to the state, flow.

i want to remove id 1 from 2020-06-15:[] 

and

I want to move id 1 to 2020-06-01:[]..

but via variables, so lets say selectedDate and selectedId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will delete an element from one array, optionally adding it to a different array.

```js
function modifyObject(obj, date, id, destinationDate) {
  let elements = obj[date];
  let elIndex = elements.findIndex(el => el.id === id);
  if (elIndex === -1) { throw `${date} id ${id} not found`; }
  
  let elDeleted = elements.splice(elIndex, 1);
  if (destinationDate) {
    let destEls = obj[destinationDate];
    if (!destEls) { throw `destinationDate ${date} not found`; }
    destEls = destEls.concat(elDeleted);
  }
}

const curObject = {
  "2020-06-15": [
    { id: "1", name: "something 1" },
    { id: "6", name: "something 6" },
  ],
  "2020-06-14": [
    { id: "1", name: "something 1" },
    { id: "15", name: "something 15" },
  ],
};

modifyObject(curObject, "2020-06-15", "1", "2020-06-14");

let result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = 'Result:\n' + JSON.stringify(curObject,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```